# If $D_n=\{\frac{k}{2^n}\mid k\in \{0,...,2^n\}\}$ and $D=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}D_n$, why $\overline{D}=[0,1[$ and not $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $$D_n=\{\frac{k}{2^n}\mid k\in \{0,...,2^n\}\}$$ and $$D=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}D_n,$$ why $\overline{D}=[0,1)$ and not $[0,1]$ ? (because $1\in D_n$ for all $n$, so $1$ should be in $\bar D$)

It's written on this article :

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Maybe considering subspace topology?

Comment: I think the author intends to denote $D$ as the set of dyadic number in $[0,1)$ *excluding $1$*, and that (s)he has made a typo by omitting $-1$ in $\{0,1,\dots,2^m-1\}$ in the definition of $D_m$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: If so, don't we have that $\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}\to 1$ when $n\to \infty$ ? So $\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$ is a sequence of dyadic that converge to 1, and thus $1\in \bar D$ ?

Comment: It looks like [0,1[ is being used as the _base_ space (or universe, depending on your preferred terminology) for the discussion, rather than all of $\mathbb{R}$; thus, the closure of $D$ _within_ this base space is still [0,1[ because 1 is not an element of the base space to begin with.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I see. But in general, it should be $[0,1]$ right ?

Comment: By the way, in general, can I take $D_n=\{k/2^n\mid k\in \{0,...,2^{n}\}\}$ instead of $D_n=\{k/2^n\mid k\in \{0,...,2^{n}-1\}\}$ ?

Comment: @lovemath If you're talking about all of $\mathbb{R}$, then yes, that would be the closure of $D$ within $\mathbb{R}$. As to what set you should take for $D_n$, I don't think there's really a canonical answer; it depends entirely on the uses it's being put to, and there are cases where either one makes sense.